# Kohana 3.2 - How do you send variables whith your routing?

Tags: php, routes, kohana, url-routing, kohana-3

I have the following route set at the end of the route list for my site which allows a final check on the uri value to provide my site users with a vanity URL (`http://example.com/username`)

```
Route::set('profile', '<path>/(<page>)', 
    array(
        "path" => "[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+",
        "page" => (blog|photos)))
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'welcome',
    'action'     => 'profile'
));
```

This route directs properly to the `welcome` controller and the `profile` method, however I was wondering if there was a way to get the `path` and `page` values sent to the method like so:

```
action_profile($var1, $var2) {
    echo $var1 . ' ' . $var2;
}
```

I don't want to rely on `$this->request->uri()` and exploding the result into an array unless there is absolutely no other way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the manuals please: http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/routing#request-parameters. `$this->request->param('param-name')` will helps.

Comment: I honestly did not see that in the docs. Their documentation is very messy to be honest and a lot of things are missing for beginners, it's like they don't want new people learning it!